# How to modify c3.js legend's text color

Tags: css, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying in vain to change the font color of a c3.js graph's legend.

With chrome's style inspector, i could change for example the font-size of the text but not the color.

Attaching a screenshot with the above mentioned properties (font-size and color).

Any hints please?

[image: screenshot of style inspector]

Answer (score 3):

It is not `color` that you should change, instead change `stroke`or `fill`. See [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html) for an explanation and difference between stroke and fill.

Answer (score 3):

Add CSS styling for the legend item in your css file. Use fill instead of color because css property color is not valid here

```
    .c3-legend-item {
       fill: #9fabb1;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you add some explanation to your answer as not every person reading this post would understand what you are showing them.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.